# How do I add polygons to fill a face?

Tags: edit-mode, faces

trying to recreate this Elijah bottle. I have two sides, one of which is outlined in red. How do I fill that face with polygons so I can then grab the center (that red square dot) to pull it outward thereby creating the slight outward bowing of the bottle?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never heard of grid fill until now. But I'll search how to do it  --thanks for the hint / how to.

Comment: So I tried Grid fill by selecting 5 vertices on each side, cntrl F, grid fill and I got the message "Loops are not connected by wire/boundary edges" --which I need help translating to layman's terms please... I also tried selecting ALL the edges and still got the smae message

Comment: The weak spot of blender is indeed the documentation and the incredible amount of useless tutorials out there... Try https://cgcookie.com/learn-blender/ or other of the resources listed here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/32990#32990

Comment: As for the grid fill,  It would be best if the bottle follows the same topology of the rest of the bottle. Can you upload your file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select all the vertices on the edge and do [Grid fill](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html?highlight=grid%20fill#grid-fill)

[image]

Then select a few vertices on the center, enable proportional editing and pull them to create the shape you need.

In your case there is a big ugly n-gon that you need to delete in order to make grid fill work.

[image]

Now the grid fill operation also makes another issue evident in your model: the subdivisions and number of vertices are not the same on both sides of your model. Undo the grid fill, add loop cuts to fix the assymmetry making both side of the model have the same number of loop cuts. Now  select the edges and do the grid fill.  Your model should work just fine now.

[image]

Then just enable proportional editing to create the bulge you are after.

[image]

Comment: Dood! You are the Saint of Blender Stack!  Thank you, I always  learn so much from you.