# Best way to make a face

Tags: modeling

simple question, I would like to know that is the best solution for cleaning my mesh?

[image]
[image]

Maybe the knife?

https://framapic.org/5XTvfkM6DXRk/FxI8lQx6iRTd.gif

Comment: Try **grid fill**: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45894/how-do-i-fill-an-area-with-faces-lined-up-in-a-grid/45899#45899 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43287/how-do-i-add-polygons-to-fill-a-face/43288#43288

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the grid loop, key <kbd>Space</kbd>, type *Grid Fill*, and select the option.

[image]

Example on a cylinder:

[image]

Comment: This is good but not in my case, this is the result i have https://framapic.org/jdgQltMJKvvO/RQxBYBehVvO8.JPG

Comment: @softyodayoann The fill worked fine. The photo shows a different issue. Go to the _properties panel > object modifiers tab_ and add an _Edge Split_ modifier. That will clear up the weird shading. Also, if my answer helped, please consider accepting it.